# Implementing Urban Airship with Phonegap for Ios get stuck on registering

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement Urban Airship using phone gap and had followed everything in the following url:

https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/66970-implementing-with-phonegap

Once the app launched, I get stuck on registering. after I click the Register button.

My setup is Xcode 4.2 Build 4D199 and I'm using Phonegap 1.1.0.

Let me know if anybody need more info to help me solve this problem.  Thank you.

The following is my xcode console log

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-138-25
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x2d03]
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x2d03]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: No copy of dns.so found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
2011-10-26 11:34:19.837 UAPhoneGap[2395:307] active
[Switching to process 12803 thread 0x3203]
2011-10-26 11:34:21.250 UAPhoneGap[2395:307] Device initialization: DeviceInfo = {"name":"Michelle W’s iPodTouch","uuid":"beb3dbb33a034930cffc6bb80e754e9174db9c40","platform":"iPod touch","gap":"1.1.0","version":"4.2.1","connection":{"type":"wifi"}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure out how to solve this problem. The problem is that I was running Phonegap 1.1.0 and the UAPhoneGap sample listed here https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/66970-implementing-with-phonegap is running Phonegap 1.0.0.

In order to fix this all you have to do is to replace phonegap1.0.0.js with phonegap1.1.0.js and replace the reference to it in index.html.

Don't forget to add go.urbanairship.com to your external white list in the phonegap plist.